# Autowired session-scoped object with null fields when debugging (IntelliJ)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, intellij-idea, autowired

Pretty new to Spring Boot here so would appreciate some help. I've managed to create a session-scoped component (using @SessionScope annotation).  This component is designed to store user information for the given session for my web app.

**SessionComponent.java**

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class SessionComponent {
     private String sessionId;
     private User user;

     // Getters and setters

}
```

**AnotherClass.java**

```
@Component
public class AnotherClass {
    @Autowired
    private SessionComponent session;

    public void method() {
        // Breakpoint here
        System.out.println(session.getSessionId());
    }
}
```

The code works fine in practice. For example, I can be in AnotherClass having @Autowired my SessionComponent in, and the code works.

However, SessionComponent doesn't appear properly in my IDE's debugger (variable view). I am using IntelliJ Community Edition. When I set a breakpoint in AnotherClass (as below), session's fields all appear as 'null' in the debugger. However, using the evaluate expression tool allows me to run `session.getSessionId()` and returns the correct result.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: i also do face the same issue with request scoped beans.